# Power consumption of the built-in monitor on my laptop

Tags: windows, monitoring, display, power-management

I am looking for a program that can show the power consumption of my built-in monitor on my laptop (MSI GS76, Windows 10).

[LocalCooling](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Local-Cooling.shtml) (gratis, non-portable)  ([mirror](https://archive.org/details/local-cooling)) sums up all the displays, but I just want to see the power consumption of the built-in monitor on my laptop, without having to disconnect my external monitor.

[image]

Comment: I don't think the tool shown in the included screen shot is applicable for laptops. The estimated power usage would better suite to a gaming desktop PC, but laptops are more optimized for minimum power consumption because of the battery. Additionally it seems to show a maximum usage not a typical usage while most of the components are at idle state. IMHO if you want to see the power usage of your computer you have to use an external measurement tool that is seated between power plug and socket and then measure the power consumption in different usage scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for the info!